# Is there a faster way to download Ubuntu?

Tags: downloads, download-speed

I want to download Ubuntu 12.04, but it seems to take a long time, i.e. 1 day via Google Chrome, or Mozilla Firefox.

Can you suggest an alternative way to download it faster (e.g. 2 hours)??

Comment: Please remember to accept/upvote the best answer to your question (tick/check mark on the left). This way, the question is marked as "answered" and future readers can refer to it knowing the solution works. Thank you...:)

Answer (score 19):

I find the bit torrent downloads to be MUCH faster than the direct links.

Check out http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/alternative-downloads and select the desktop version you need (*i386* is 32bit ubuntu; *amd64* is 64bit ubuntu).

Comment: The BitTorrent Download is REALLY Fast (got it in 20 minutes).  I loved it!!!

Comment: But he says, it takes a long time (1 day). Is it normal with regular downloads?. I think his problem is his Internet speed.

Comment: @AnwarShah you may be right, but bit torrent is a better alternative than direct download (and it's easily resumable if you get disconnected).

Comment: @amc agreed, But the difference between a regular download and a torrent download should not be that **huge**.

Comment: A normal download for me takes about 1 hour

Comment: What about ISPs that block BitTorrent?

Comment: bitorrent download is at least 10 times faster

Answer (score 8):

Yes,  find another mirror in your own country , if you're not in america.

Pick a [mirror here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/alternative-downloads)

Comment: +1 as torrent download may be blocked by corporate policy and does not always available

Comment: Exact link: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+cdmirrors

Answer (score 4):

> I want to download Ubuntu 12.04, but it seems that it take a long time

The time to download depends both on the speed of your internet connection and on your geographical location. Do you know what kind of connection you have? If not, you can get an estimate of your speed by visiting [this test site](http://www.speedtest.net).

If you can edit the question to include your country of residence, a server (mirror) closer to you can be recommended, which may be faster.

Answer (score 2):

My Suggestion would be to use the combination
firefox web browser and the [DownthemAll](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/downthemall/) firefox plugin.
I have been using the combination for a while and so far is quite fast and you have the option of pausing your downloads and most other cool options

Answer (score 1):

You may need a multi-thread download utility, like `axel`. Or P2P download software, such as BitTorrent, eMule. After you have installed the basic Ubuntu system, you may also try `apt-fast` to download individiual packages faster.

Answer (score 1):

You can download the iso directly from Ubuntu.com. I am guessing this is what you have done and found it hard to download.
I use FlareGet. It is a simple Program that will download your file in segments.
also using the command wget you can download and resume downloads

```
wget -c <paste your download link here>
```

Then there are solutions like the torrent downloads. These can vary in speed depending on the peers.

Answer (score 1):

[Flareget](http://sourceforge.net/projects/flareget/) is the best and fastest downloader. 
It is alternative option Of IDM for Ubuntu.