# Ubuntu download problems

Tags: downloads

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a faster way to download Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/134777/is-there-a-faster-way-to-download-ubuntu)

I was downloading Ubuntu from www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop and in the middle of the download my monitor display became white and when it restarted Windows had crashed. I'm pretty eager to try Ubuntu because of its speed and stability.
Are there any alternatives to download Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

**Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS (Precise Pangolin)**

You can use torrent.

- **[ubuntu-12.04.1-dvd-amd64.iso.torrent](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/precise/release/ubuntu-12.04.1-dvd-amd64.iso.torrent)**
- **[ubuntu-12.04.1-dvd-i386.iso.torrent](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/precise/release/ubuntu-12.04.1-dvd-i386.iso.torrent)**

**[Ubuntu Precise Release Image](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/precise/release/)**